# Преобразование с помощью android studio фона в различное форматы разрешения

Tags: android, android-studio, изображения

Можно ли и как с помощью android Studio загрузить картинку фона в приложении , чтобы она преобразовалась сразу в форматы ldpi, mdpi, hdpi, xhdpi,xxhdpi,xxxhdpi
и какие разрешения при этом должны быть

Comment: фона чего (экрана, виджета, ..)?

Comment: фона в моем приложении (картинка бэкграунд в лайаут)

Comment: А есть ли смысл? Многие из этих форматов уже морально устарели, а остальные прекрасно съедаются современными устройствами, даже если не совпадают

Answer (score 4, accepted):

С помощью плагина для Android Studio или IntelliJ IDEA [Android Drawable Importer](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7658-android-drawable-importer)